# We might not be ..., but …

Tags: négation, conjonctions

How can a sentence like 'we might not be married, but we love each other very much' be translated?

Is the translation, 'nous ne pouvons être pas mariés, mais nous nous aimons beaucoup' correct?

Comment: Your translation *(nous ne pouvons être pas mariés, mais nous nous aimons beaucoup)* means *“We cannot not be maried, but we love each other very much”*, so it's not what you're looking for. Also, the first part is not properly structured: it should be *“nous ne pouvons pas ne pas être mariés”*, but then again, the meaning is not what you intended it to be in the first place. The answers already provided are good, but since they do not comment your translation, I added this comment to help you with it.

Answer (score 3):

> Nous avons beau ne pas être mariés, nous nous aimons beaucoup.

A more litteral translation for the first part would be :

> Nous ne sommes peut-être pas mariés, mais...

But as a french man, I would have naturally gone with the first phrase. Don't ask me why, it was instinctive.

Comment: Je dirais que votre première version indique qu'en dépit de votre union non-consacrée, vous vous aimez *(la consécration de l'union n'est qu'une formalité à l'amour, pas la source de l'amour)*, alors que votre deuxième version confronterait davantage: nous ne sommes peut-être pas mariés *(comme vous l'êtes)*, mais nous nous aimons *(alors qu'il est clair que VOUS êtes indifférents l'un à l'autre et menez vos vies en parallèle)*. Oui? Non?

Comment: Damn... ça fait longtemps que j'ai arreté les études 'actives' de textes... pour que le deuxième cas confronte, il faudrait une ajouter une emphase sur le premier nous, qui se traduirait par "Nous, on n'est peut-être pas marié, mais...". Sans cette emphase, il me faut du contexte pour choisir et décider du sens profond.

Comment: Je comprendrais le *«peut-être»* comme le premier porteur de contraste, mais il est vrai qu'il n'est pas forcément hostile. Le ton, à l'oral, participera beaucoup à l'interprétation finale, il est vrai. À l'écrit, le contexte ou une explicitation du ton leverait sans doute l'ambiguïté...

Answer (score 1):

Real-life **spoken** French would be something like:

> Peut-être qu'on est pas mariés, mais on s'aime quand même beaucoup.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> On n’est peut-être pas mariés, mais ça n'empêche qu'on s'aime beaucoup.
>
> C’est pas parce qu’on n’est pas mariés qu'on ne s'aime pas beaucoup, bien au contraire.
>
> On a beau ne pas être mariés, on ne s'en aime pas moins beaucoup.

Comment: The last one sounds weird. Instead, I'd suggest: “on ne s'en aime pas moins pour autant”.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. This weirdness you feel -- does it come from the adjacent placement of "moins" and "beaucoup"? I suppose it looks as if "moins" qualifies "beaucoup", just like "moins courageux", whereas in fact "moins" is part of the expression.

Comment: Any other adverb would sound unusual. It could grammatically be acceptable but only if the expression is used to say that there is no impact on the intensity of  the adverb itself. But here *moins* can't modify *beaucoup*. *Moins beaucoup* or *plus beaucoup* is gibberish grammar, which you'd only find in deliberately non-grammatical language (children in particular may find it funny).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Interesting that you find it weird. I don't. Our personal exposure to French as a first language created a nice contrast here!

Comment: [*«Cela ne les rend pas moins beaucoup plus crédibles.»*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1200508p/f429.image), juste au-dessus du nom de l'auteur en bas à droite, *in Le Grand dictionnaire de la philosophie* (éditions Larousse)...

Comment: @Feelew Hi. If you omit the expression "n'en ... pas moins", you're left with the phrase "on s'aime beaucoup". And this is exactly what I want to say here. The way I see it, if the phrase that you're left with makes sense, the sentence as a whole is considered grammatical. What do you think? --- "*on* **ne** *s*'**en** *aime* **pas moins** *beaucoup*"

Comment: @Feelew e.g.: "*il* **n'en** *reste* **pas moins** *possible*" === "il reste possible (malgré ce que je viens de dire)"

Comment: @Feelew: Ok, thanks for pointing this out. Maybe my disliking this phrasing is due to semantic reasons. I realize now that I wouldn't find the sentence weird with *éperdument*, although *passionément* or *beaucoup* would put me off.

Comment: @Alone-zee No problem with your phrasing on my end, though it is obvious that the clash of *«moins beaucoup»* was so strong for Stéphane that he didn't naturally go back to reinterpret it into *«pas moins / beaucoup»*. I feel no weirdness into this, but Stéphane obviously also knows his French quite well.